# Troubleshooting android displaying error"Unfortunately app has stopped working"

Tags: android

i have created an android app on google maps through eclipse,there are no errors but when i install it on emulator or any android device and run it,error message is displayed that "unfortunately app has stopped working".
please guide me for the troubleshooting.
this is the java main activity file :-

```
      package com.example.droidloc;

  import java.util.List;

  import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.app.Activity;
   import android.app.AlertDialog;
  import android.content.DialogInterface;

   import com.google.android.maps.MapActivity;
   import com.google.android.maps.MapView;
  import com.google.android.maps.Overlay;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;

 public class MainActivity extends MapActivity {
 MapView map;
long start;
long stop;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.mainmap);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    touchy t =new touchy();
    List<Overlay> overlayList = map.getOverlays();
    overlayList.add(t);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

class touchy extends Overlay
{
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent e,MapView m)
    {
        if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            start=e.getEventTime();
        }
        if(e.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            stop=e.getEventTime();
        }
        if(stop-start>1500)
        {
            AlertDialog alert=new                           

                 AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();
            alert.setTitle("Pick an Option");
            alert.setMessage("Pick an Option dude");
            alert.setButton2("Pin a Point", new        

               DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1)      
     {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }
            });
            alert.show();
            return true;

        }
        return false ;
    }
    }

@Override
protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}


      }
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is the xml file :-

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/mainmap"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:clickable="true"
      />

---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

this is the manifest file :-

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.droidloc"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0" >

  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
      <uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.droidloc.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="AIzaSyAlHKiaTa8KrABuGHIvcuZ4IiBFifqOu1s"/>
  </application>

  </manifest>
```

Comment: you need add following line too in application tag: `<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`

Comment: You need to look at your exception stacktrace as the very first thing.

Comment: please look at this : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start i think you mix up old and new google map implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I think Your Fragment can not cast to MapView. so it could be your classcastexception . if not than you shoud post your logcat output.

try by use this in your Layout may be solve problem:

```
<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/mainmap" 
android:layout_below="@+id/innerrelativelay" />
```

or

```
<fragment
android:id="@+id/mainmap"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of things missing. Heres a list of what I saw, and some are from comments:

1. You are extending mapActivity which is based on versio 1 of google maps android. But in xml you are using mapfragment v2 of google maps android.
2. You should extend FragmentActivity or any other activity like ActionBarActivity that extends from FragmentActivity.
3. You are missing metadata tag in manifest file.
4. Min sdk version is 8 so you need to use SupportMapFragment in xml you are using mapfragment which is available above api 11.

Comment: all of the above suggested debugs tried and tested , but none is working .